# Android : MediaPlayer : How to disable audio when seeking

Tags: android, media-player

I am using mediaplayer class to play audio, in which i am using seekTo, onSeekCompletion() routines to implement seeking.

My problem is that while seeking i can hear sound. How to avoid playing sound while seeking.

One option that i have is to pause first then do seek. but Is there other settings or Mediaplayer API to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to do the pause thing manually, as you're saying it. I haven't come across any such option in media player. look for onProgressChanged event of seek bar.

Comment: Yes, that solution is there, but is there other solutions to do so ??

Comment: I don't know any other as of now buddy. haven't worked with MediaPlayer enough.